# Does the fundamental theorem of calculus require continuity of the function being integrated?

Tags: complex-analysis, real-analysis

The (first) fundamental theorem of calculus is [typically stated](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Calculus#Fundamental_Theorem_of_Calculus) as follows, assuming continuity of the given function:

- Suppose that *f* is continuous on the closed interval *[a,b]* and *F*
  is defined by $F(x)= \int_a^x f(t)\ dt.$ Then  *F* is differentiable
  on *(a,b)* and for all $x\in(a,b)$, we have $F'(x) = f(x)$.

One (apparent) application of this theorem is in the proof that the winding number of a closed path is an integer. One example is [lemma 1.1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WZX4GEpxPRgC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=proof%20winding%20numbers%20integers&source=bl&ots=vziSPml5KA&sig=M-kx3RO31NiQyWZhak26i_DI518&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwA2oVChMI6c7ZrcLCxwIVTijbCh0Kiwx2#v=onepage&q=proof%20winding%20numbers%20integers&f=false) of Lang's textbook *Complex Analysis*. (A very similar proof appears on page 115 of a book with the same title by LV Ahlfors.) The key step is to form the definite integral of a certain function and immediately take the derivative, getting the same function back. But the proof includes no argument that the function in question is continuous, and indeed the function could be undefined on a finite number of points in the interval. (It involves a derivative of a piecewise differentiable path.) It is possible to show that the integral exists, however. Is this a sufficient condition for the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: For a piecewise continuous function $f$, the statement probably changes to $F'=f$ a.e.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more general version of the fundamental theorem of calculus appears in most introductory measure theory textbooks:

> Suppose that $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and Lebesgue integrable.  Set $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ (Lebesgue integral).  Then at almost every point $x \in [a,b]$, $F$ is differentiable at $x$ and $F'(x) = f(x)$.

More precisely, there is a set $A \subset [a,b]$ whose Lebesgue measure is zero, such that for every $x \in [a,b] \setminus A$ we have that $F$ is differentiable at $x$ and $F'(x) = f(x)$.

$F$ also satisfies the stronger property of being [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Definition) on $[a,b]$.  Indeed, a "converse" of this fundamental theorem of calculus is that every absolutely continuous function $G : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ may be written $G(x) = G(a) + \int_a^x g(t)\,dt$ for some measurable and Lebesgue integrable function $g$, which is unique up to measure-zero sets.

See, for instance, Theorem 3.35 of Folland's *Real Analysis*.

You may of course replace the codomain $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{C}$ simply by taking real and imaginary parts.  More general vector spaces are also possible, with appropriate modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. This looks helpful. Is there any result of this general character for Kurzweil-Henstock gauge integration?

Comment: @LawrencePaulson: I don't know off the top of my head, but if there is, I'd expect it to be discussed in most any book on the K-H gauge integral.  I did find http://planetmath.org/fundamentaltheoremofcalculusforkurzweilhenstockintegral but that is somewhat different.  It is more like my converse statement, and its assumption would be that $G$ is *everywhere* differentiable.  An everywhere differentiable function need not be absolutely continuous, nor vice versa.

Comment: @LawrencePaulson: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral) says that you can extend this FTC to the case where $f$ is K-H integrable, and get the conclusion that $F$ is a.e. differentiable and $F' = f$ a.e.  Of course if $f$ is K-H but not Lebesgue integrable, your $F$ will not be absolutely continuous.

Comment: Thanks, these are helpful suggestions. It's still frustrating that multiple textbooks on complex analysis gloss over such critical details without the smallest remark. Can you suggest a book on complex analysis that's rigorous? I'd heard that Ahlfors was good, but clearly not if details matter.

Comment: @LawrencePaulson: Well, it sounds like the case you actually care about has $f$ piecewise continuous, and in that case it's a very direct extension of the usual Calculus I FTC: just apply it on each "piece".  You don't need any fancier integration theory.  As for complex analysis books, I don't have a lot of experience there, but I know some people like John B. Conway's books.

Comment: Frankly, I don't think measure theory and a.e statements have much to do with what Ahlfors or Lange have in mind. I looked at Lang, and he's careful to mention that the derivative exists only on the interior of the subintervals in question.

Comment: The integrand here involves the derivative of a piecewise continuous path, and therefore the critical thing is that this derivative is continuous. This doesn't hold in general. It would probably suffice for the derivative to be continuous almost everywhere on [a,b].

Regarding the FTC, I've managed to prove that F' = f at x if f is continuous at x and provided f is integrable over the interval.

Comment: @LawrencePaulson: At the bottom of Lang's page 133 it says that curves are assumed piecewise $C^1$ (and of course they must be continuous).  That means the derivative is piecewise continuous, and so I think the usual freshman calculus theorems are sufficient.  The FTC will hold everywhere except the finitely many points where $F$ fails to be $C^1$.

Comment: That's sorted then, thanks!