# What is "improper" about improper integrals of type 2?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

What is the technical reason that one cannot integrate over vertical asymptotes?

I know integrals like $\int_{-1}^1-\frac{1}{x^2}dx$ are improper integrals of type 2 and that one should divide the domain in $[-1,0)$ and $(0,1]$.

But why exactly? What is it about the nature of integration that it wouldn't work to directly integrate over $[-1,1]$?

Comment: The singularity at $x=0$ presents the biggest problem. We can't bound the integrand near zero.

Comment: maybe because the primitive  function $-\frac1{x}$ is not continuous at 0, basically because is not defined (neither the function itself is defined at 0). I don't know but it seems quite natural to think that it's not possible to integrate over a point that is not included in the domain.

Comment: @RamiroScorolli The definition of the integrand at a single point doesn't really matter.  It's undboundedness that's the problem.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Why do we have to bound it per se?

Comment: @GambitSquared: the definition of Riemann integral applies only to bounded functions defined on a closed interval. Hence "we have to bound it per se".

Comment: The Riemann integral is the only number between all the upper sums and all the lower sums.  If the function is unbounded, there are no upper sums.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** *Please notice the comment below this answer. I realized that the word "continuous" is not accurate enough in the text below. With some research I realized that the topic of integration for non-continuous and negative functions is too complex for me (e.g. [Lebesgue's Theory of Integration: Its Origins and Development](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/lebesgues-theory-of-integration-its-origins-and-development)), and that I was not aware of what is involved. Having said that, I will keep the answer un-deleted in case some one benefits from the references and the comment below.*

The problem is that the function is not continuous for all points in the range [-1, 1]. We have to break the integral range to 2 intervals first. The point of discontinuity here is obviously.

Here is a good short video:

[Improper Integral of type II](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408s/AS/LM7-8-5.html)

Also, the answer here may be of further interest:
[Does the fundamental theorem of calculus require continuity of the function being integrated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429872/does-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-require-continuity-of-the-function-bein)

Comment: It would be nice from the down-voter to educate me/us on what is wrong in addition to casting the vote.

Comment: While I am not the downvoter, the problem with your answer is that you think discontinuity is the reason for splitting interval or treating it as improper integral. Also one can use fundamental theorem for discontinuous functions provided an anti-derivative exists. Continuity is only sufficient but not necessary for existence of an anti-derivative.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you very much for your explanation. I did not know that.

Comment: +1 for the edit which is an evidence of an honest attempt to improve your post.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, this is really so kind of you sir. Thanks again,

Answer (score 1):

If you directly integrate $$\int _{-1}^1 \frac {-1}{x^2} dx$$ you come up with the answer $$\int _{-1}^1 \frac {-1}{x^2}dx=2$$

When you sketch the graph you will see the graph is below the $x$-axis, so obviously the answer is wrong.

Comment: I know that the answer is wrong, I can also calculate it, but I don't understand the technical reason for why it is wrong...

Comment: That is how the improper integrals are defined so the answer agrees with our intuition and makes sense.

Comment: I would argue that use of Newton-Leibniz formula is not direct integration. It only works under certain conditions. Riemann sum, for example, would be direct integration, and in this case it shows why there is a problem with the integral, as the usually definited limit doesn't exist. (I still upvoted the answer, it's a good example)

Comment: +1 for @YuriyS comment, a typical evaluation of integral via anti-derivatives assumes that the integrand is continuous (more generally it should be Riemann integrable and possess an anti-derivative).

Answer (score 1):

The Riemann integral itself has this property:
$$
\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{x^2} = \int_{-1}^0\frac{dx}{x^2} + \int_{0}^1\frac{dx}{x^2}.\tag{$1$}
$$
But this integral is not Riemann integrable, and ($1$) fails.  We cannot compute $(-\infty)+(+\infty)$ to get $0$.  As far as the theory of the Riemann integral is concerned, this integral does not exist.  So it has to be done in some other way.  The standard way to do it is the "improper integral" you mention.

A second way, which lacks important properties such as ($1$), but is preferred by physicists, is the "princpal value":
$$
\text{PV}\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{x^2} = \lim_{\delta \to 0^+}\left(\int_{-1}^{-\delta}\frac{dx}{x^2} + \int_{\delta}^1\frac{dx}{x^2}\right).\tag{$2$}
$$

Thirdly (I claim) the Lebesgue integral is superior to the Riemann integral for this  purpose in that it allows computation of integrals for unbounded functions, and for functions undefined on a set of measure zero.